# Use two buttons in the same form for invisible reCAPTCHA

Tags: html, forms, button, recaptcha, invisible

I'm trying to implement the new invisible reCAPTCHA, from Google.
It's all working perfectly, but my forms always have two submit buttons, that does different things with the input.

I tried to simply add another `<button>` in my form, but reCAPTCHA only recognizes the first one in code.

I can't think of any reason that would prevent the other button to work properly. Here is a simple example of what I tried:

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" value="textfield"/><br/>
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekey" data-callback='onSubmit'
        value="anaction">An action</button>
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekey" data-callback='onSubmit'
        value="anotheraction">Another action</button>
</form>
```

I usually tell apart the two buttons by making an `isset` on the `POST` values. Here it doesn't seem to work with the second button. If I switch the two lines, it will make the other button submit properly.

If someone has an idea about this, I'll thank him for enlightments.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I fixed it like below:

```
<button type="submit" class="g-recaptcha"
                id="captcha1"
                data-sitekey="YOUR_SECRETKEY"
                data-callback="sendData">button</button>

<button type="submit" class="g-recaptcha"
                id="captcha2"
                data-sitekey="YOUR_SECRETKEY"
                data-callback="sendData">button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".g-recaptcha").each(function() {
        var object = $(this);
        grecaptcha.render(object.attr("id"), {
            "sitekey" : "YOUR_SITEKEY",
            "callback" : function(token) {
                object.parents('form').find(".g-recaptcha-response").val(token);
                object.parents('form').submit();
            }
        });
    });
  }
);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it kind of works. Recaptcha is always asking for confirmation though. I have another problem, now the recaptcha never seems to be valid. You put the function sendData, but it's not defined on the code you pasted. I assume the function sendData send the form using a getElementById ?

Comment: Yes, I posted you the function

Answer (score 1):

Yes I created a function sendData like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sendData(){
    var test = $("#test").val();

    if(test != ""){
        $.post( "page.php",
            { 'g-recaptcha-response': grecaptcha.getResponse(), 'test' : test})
                .done(function( data ) {

                   console.log(data);
               }
        );
    }else{
        console.log(data);
    }

    grecaptcha.reset(); //important

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stash the token in a `hidden` field and use it instead of the `g-recaptcha-response` value to send your verification request.  You can distinguish between the two submissions by saving the `action` item in the JSON return object.  I have no idea why this works, by the way.

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
        document.getElementById("token").value = token;
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
</script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<form id="form" action="page.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token">
...
<button type="submit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."
        data-callback="onSubmit" data-action="action">An Action</button>
<button type="submit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."
        data-callback="onSubmit" data-action="anotheraction">Another Action</button>
</form>
```